# Hide android status bar on menu selection

Tags: android

I am trying to hide the android status bar from my activity using the following code:

[image: Status Bar I want to hide]

oncreate code:

```
    // set as full screen
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    // Hide the status bar.
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // set as full screen
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    // Hide the status bar.
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}

protected void onWindowFocusChanged() {
    // set as full screen
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    // Hide the status bar.
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```

The status bar is hidden until I select the menu (code below for the menu):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.help) {
        homehelp = 0; // reset the homehelp logic
        homehelp(); // call it to display
    }
    return false;
}
```

Any selection that inflates the menu displays the status bar - the status bar then remains until I force a resume with Power Off/On or cycling away from my activity.

Can someone offer a suggestion how to keep the status bar hidden with menu inflation / selection ?

Thanks;

Andy

Comment: Can you add an image of what exactly status bar do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.help) {
        homehelp = 0; // reset the homehelp logic
        homehelp(); // call it to display
    }

    // set as full screen
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    // Hide the status bar.
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: That works if i select something from the menu, if i dont select anything from the menu then the status bar remains

Comment: I am not really sure of what you can do but try it in the oncreateoptionmenu since the status bar appears after the menu cycle has been toggled

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean winChange){
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(winChange);

        if(winChange){
           View decorView = getWindow.getDecorView();
           int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
           decorView.setSystemVisibility(uiOptions)
        }
}
```

Comment: As your question is pretty short you might also add more information - the more you explain the easier it is for others to help you. Good luck!